# Obtener indice de ViewPager que se muestra en pantalla Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

Tengo un ViewPager situado en la parte inferior de mi app, y estoy tratando de obtener su indice, id o alguna referencia al ViewPager que se encuentra mostrándose en pantalla para que según cual se muestre, el botón que compartan haga una acción u otra en l método onClick(). Una idea básica de lo que planteó es:

```
    //Funcion de escucha del Button
    Button btnTick = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonInvertirTick);
    btnTick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v) {
             if(index1.isShowed()==true){
               //Tareas a realizar
             } else (index2.isShowed()==true){
               //Tareas a realizar
             }
        }
    });
```

Adjunto código

fragment_screen_slide_page.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvIndex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/valores"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:inputType="phone" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LayoutEditText"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonInvertirTick"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/success"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

ScreenSlidePageFragment.java:

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

/**
 * Key to insert the background color into the mapping of a Bundle.
 */
private static final String BACKGROUND_COLOR = "color";

/**
 * Key to insert the index page into the mapping of a Bundle.
 */
private static final String INDEX = "index";

/**
 * Key to insert the text into the mapping of a Bundle.
 */
private static final String TEXTO = "index";

private int color;
private int index;
private String textoSta;

/**
 * Instancia un nuevo fragment con un background color, el indice de la pagina y un texto
 *
 * @param color background color
 * @param index index page
 * @param texto texto de tipo de cotizacion
 * @return a new page
 */
public static ScreenSlidePageFragment newInstance(int color, int index, String texto) {

    // Instantiate a new fragment
    ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();

    // Save the parameters
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(BACKGROUND_COLOR, color);
    bundle.putInt(INDEX, index);
    bundle.putString(TEXTO, texto);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragment.setRetainInstance(true);

    return fragment;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Carga los parametros con los que se sobrecargo cuando la precarga inicial del fragment se completa
    this.color = (getArguments() != null) ? getArguments().getInt(
            BACKGROUND_COLOR) : Color.DKGRAY;

    this.textoSta = (getArguments() != null) ? getArguments().getString(TEXTO)
            : "";
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

    // Establece el texto del TextView con el que se sobrecargo
    TextView tvIndex = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvIndex);
    tvIndex.setText(textoSta);

    // Establece el color de fondo con el que se sobrecargo
    rootView.setBackgroundColor(color);

    //Funcion de escucha del Button
    Button btnTick = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonInvertirTick);
    btnTick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v) {
            Context context = getActivity();
            CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    });




    return rootView;

}
}
```

La manera en la que instancio el ViewPager en las clases:

```
        // Instantiate a ViewPager
    pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    // Create an adapter with the fragments we show on the ViewPager
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.backgroundPager), 0, "Saldo a invertir: "));
    adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.backgroundPager), 1, "Valores a comprar: "));
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Espero vuestra ayuda !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde la API 22 puedes usar el método [getCurrentItem()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem()) del `ViewPager`.

```
int index = pager.getCurrentItem();
```

---

Pero también puedes obtenerla mediante [SimpleOnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.html) . Crea esta clase que es un listener para detectar la página seleccionada en el `ViewPager` :

```
public class DetailOnPageChangeListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {

    private int currentPage;

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        currentPage = position;  //*** Aquí se obtiene el indice!
    }

    public final int getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }
}
```

y asignala a tu `ViewPager`:

```
 // Instantiate a ViewPager
pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new DetailOnPageChangeListener());
```

---

o asignar directamente el listener:

```
     // Instantiate a ViewPager
pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

       private int currentPage;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
             currentPage = position;  //*** Aquí se obtiene el indice!
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }

        public final int getCurrentPage() {
           return currentPage;
        }

    });
```

Comment: He optado por crear la clase DetailOnPageChangeListener.java para instanciarla y poder obtener el view que se esta mostrando actualmente en pantalla. El problema al que me enfrento es que el listener del botón le tengo en la clase ScreenSlidePageFragment.java y es ahi donde quiero que determine si esta en un view o otro para que desencadene unas acciones u otras. En la clase donde tengo el listener del botón pager no es pager sino rootView. Pager es el nombre que le doy al objeto en las clases que llamo a ScreenSlidePageFragment.java para sobrecargarlo y empotrarlo al view que genera lasclases

Comment: aunque esa es la manera en la que lo estoy planteandolo no se si lo ideal es llamar a la clase que me comentaste crear desde cada una de las clases que instancio el viewPager con nombre de objeto pager

Answer (score 2):

Crear un `listener` y ponerlo en tu `ViewPager`:

```
/**
         * Obtener la posicion actual del ViewPager mediante
         * extendiendo SimpleOnPageChangeListener class y añadiendolo a tu método
         */
        public class DetailOnPageChangeListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {

            private int currentPage;

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                currentPage = position;
            }

            public final int getCurrentPage() {
                return currentPage;
            }
        }
```

Según el método que mencionas, en tu caso sería así, parecido al método que yo menciono, pero este no se como funciona ni si podría funcionar:

```
pageListener = new PageListener();
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);

private int currentPage;

    private static class PageListener extends SimpleOnPageChangeListener{
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.i(TAG, "página seleccionado " + position);
                   currentPage = position;
        }
    }
```

Comment: y creo una nueva clase con ese código y como referencia eso con mi clase actual?

Comment: @EduardoMéndez eso lo creas dentro de tu clase del `ViewPager` y extiendes el método, así no hace falta que referencies a ninguna clase

Comment: he implementado los dos métodos al final de mi clase de ScreenSlidePageFragment.java . El problema es que nose con que sobrecargar el método en **int position**. Básicamente estoy tratando de llamar a ese método en el onClick para que con System.out me saque en consola el index del ViewPager que se esta mostrando en pantalla

Comment: y haciendo el System.out de el método getCurrentPage() me devuelve siempre zero.... :(

Comment: @EduardoMéndez a que te refieres con sobrecargar? y si estás en la página 0 del viewpager es normal que salga cero

Comment: Me refiero que en el método onPageSelected debo pasarle un parámetro de tipo int y nose cuál. Y en cuanto a lo que me devuelve el otro método es siempre zero tanto si está en un view y pulso el botón como si trato de hacerlo en el otro view

Comment: @EduardoMéndez el parametro tipo int es el `currentPage` y sobre el error del que me hables no se el motivo, dado que a mi si me funciona, puede ser algún fallo mío al pasar código pero no consigo verlo

Comment: Indagando por el foro he visto que hay un método que saca en forma de int la pagina actual **vp.getCurrentItem()**. Pero yo no soy capaz de con rootView.getCurrentItem() conseguir que el método funcione. Se ve que con rootView no puedo aplicarle ese método. Podrías decirme cual seria en mi caso?

Comment: @EduardoMéndez respuesta actualizada

Comment: y en ese caso pager que seria?? mi rootView no por que me da fallo. Y en cuanto a la otra clase de PageListener no me deja hacerla private y static, he tenido que dejarla como public class para que no me diera fallo. ¿Puede llegar a fallar por no ser private?

Comment: @EduardoMéndez un pagelistener debe de ser public, si no no podría ser llamado en otras clases, en tu caso, coge el pager que creo que tienes de nombre `pager` y ves sustituyendo los datos del ejemplo con los tuyos propios

Comment: pager no se llama, me falla en **page.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);**

Comment: @EduardoMéndez entonces quita el código de vp y pone solo a partir de `private int`

Comment: soy incapaz de lograrlo..... Tengo una clase PageListener donde he metido el código que me pasaste modificando el acceso a la clase por public y sin static. Y en en la clase java tengo en el onClick del botón del ViewPager la instancia de la clase **PageListener pageListener = new PageListener();** y el acceso al método: **page.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);** . Y sigo sin ver donde esta la variable o objeto page ya que el Android Studio me marca como fallo al no encontrarla.

Comment: @EduardoMéndez pues entonce más no te puedo ayudar lo siento, esperemos a ver si alguien puede solucionarlo

Comment: no se de donde sacas el **page** por lo demás el programa no me pone trabas